# SQL Server query with treelist child names in one column and join table

Tags: sql-server, treelist

I have 3 tables:

**Article**:

```
Id, Name, Gropu, Measure, Price
----------------------------------
1, Coffee, 2, 1, 2.95
2, Tea, 2, 1, 1.95
3, CocaCola, 1, 1, 2,95
```

**Measure**:

```
Id, Name
---------
1, Cup
```

**Group**:

```
Id, ParentId, Name
----------------------
1, null, Beverages
2, 1, Hot beverages
```

So idea is to join all tables and get data like on table below

```
Article.Id, Article.Name, Article.Group, Group.Name, Article.Measure, Measure.Name, Article.Price
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1, Coffee, 2, Beverages - Hot beverages, 1, Cup, 2.95
2, Tea, 2, Beverages - Hot beverages, 1, Cup, 1.95
3, CocaCola, 1, Beverages, 1, Cup, 2.95
```

All what I need is that I got in same column all tree list hierarchy names from top node to last one for article (in this example its only 2 levels but in reality can be infinite levels)

So I need in one column all names of hierarchy names with something between names like ' - ' from one article.

I hope someone got fast query because it has thousands of articles in the real database

Comment: Why haven't you written a query to get your results?   That's what I would do.

Comment: I need query, if you know write on my example

Comment: This is a site where people answer questions..if you need someone to just write code for you, you should hire a developer.

Comment: I need fast query, to work fast, not recursive query something faster, i'm out of ideas

Comment: If you have written a recursive query that is performing too slow, you should post it and the execution plan from it so that we can help with the real problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure there are no loops in your Group table hierarchy, and if your Group table has a lot of records, then make sure the table has an index on Id (including Name) and another index on the ParentId (also including Name).

Then something like this (can't actually test without the table definitions) should do the trick:

```
;WITH GroupHierarchy AS
(
    -- Anchor
    SELECT
        GroupId = G.Id,
        ParentId = G.ParentID,
        GroupName = G.Name,
        HierarchyName = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), G.Name),
        Level = 1
    FROM
        [Group] AS G
    WHERE
        G.ParentID IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    -- Children
    SELECT
        GroupId = G.Id,
        ParentId = G.ParentId,
        GroupName = G.Name,
        HierarchyName = R.HierarchyName + '-' + G.Name,
        Level = R.Level + 1
    FROM
        GroupHierarchy AS R
        INNER JOIN [Group] AS G ON R.GroupId = G.ParentId
)
SELECT
    A.Id, 
    A.Name, 
    A.[Group], 
    G.HierarchyName, 
    A.Measure, 
    M.Name, 
    A.Price
FROM
    Article AS A
    INNER JOIN Measure AS M ON A.Measure = M.Measure
    INNER JOIN GroupHierarchy AS G ON A.[Group] = G.[GroupId]
OPTION 
    (MAXRECURSION 1000) -- Your max recursion depth
```

If it's still slow, you can try creating a physical (or temporal) table to store the recursion results using SELECT INTO, creating a clustered index and joining afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

For what you want, there is no faster solution than a recursive query.

Comment: useless, write your faster way and I will try, word mean nothing

Comment: I'm telling you there is no faster way.   That is the answer to your question.   You say you need something faster than a recursive query.

Comment: in question is only example, what I need, I got 11 tables in joins (inner and left) also dynamic add WHERE conditions depend on users filters

Comment: None of which changes my answer.  A recursive query is still your fastest solution.

Comment: i wasn't here more than 2 years, its time to avoid this 'help' next 4 years